# .doc file into .pdf using java

Tags: apache-poi, pdf-generation, pdfbox, doc

I want to convert .doc file into .pdf file using java where .doc file can have non textual elements also(Like Image, Table etc). I have tried solution with Apache POI library where we can read text, pictures and tables and put it into pdf but format is not maintained(E.g : if we read images and put it into pdf all images will be there after one by one. After that if we read all text from .doc and put it into .pdf, all text will be after all images).

Need solution using Apache poi version 5.0.0

Comment: Upload it to Office365, and have Office online turn it into a PDF?

Comment: This should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/